# Match employee with latest clock in/out data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

This is a common question but from the questions I've browsed I wasn't able to find a good answer. For every employee I want to display their last known status and the time of that status.

I have two SQL Server tables (well actually they're views):

**Employee**

| EmployeeID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | xyz |

**Clock**

| EmployeeID | ClockType | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | I | 2022-12-19 10:00:00 |
| 123 | G | 2022-12-19 19:21:00 |

There is some more additional data there but I think I'll be able to figure that out. My problem right now is that I need to find the latest entry for every employee in a **performant** way.

Current approach:

```sql
SELECT
e.EmployeeID,
c.Time AS LastClock,
c.ClockType
FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN Clock c ON e.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID
AND c.Time = (
  SELECT max(Time) FROM Clock c1
  WHERE e.EmployeeID = c1.EmployeeID
)
```

This works, but with many millions of rows, this is really slow. I've also tried simply limiting the inner select with a condition to only return the last X days but that breaks the requirements since I need it for every employee, even if they weren't here in the past month.

What are better ways to do this? The code would be called about every minute, so performance is quite important.

Answer (score 1):

I think a reasonable way of writing it is the [following](https://dbfiddle.uk/J5WwpGhC):

```
WITH c AS (
 SELECT clock.*, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY employeeid ORDER BY time DESC) rn
 FROM clock
)
SELECT
 e.EmployeeID,
 c.Time LastClock,
 c.Clocktype
FROM Employee e
 LEFT JOIN c ON e.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID
WHERE COALESCE(c.rn, 1) = 1
```

However, I think the most important thing for performance of this (or your original query) is going to be to ensure you have a proper index on `clock` (`employeeid`, `time`). e.g. `create index ix_clock on clock (employeeid, time)`

Comment: The indexes are there already.
This might be a dumb question but isn't max() faster than an order by partition since you only need to find one max record per ID instead of sorting the whole list?

Comment: SQL isn't procedural, so without looking at an explain plan, I don't think there's a guarantee about which one will be faster. However, I expect this would be at least as fast in practice as your original query. I suspect the DB will realize it can use the index to get the rn=1 row without looking at the table, but even if it doesn't, I generally find running one large query usually gets optimized better than (potentially) running multiple subqueries like in your original.

Comment: I notice you said "indexes" plural, so I just want to confirm you have one index with both of those columns in that order (different than having an index on each of those columns and different from having it in the opposite order).

Answer (score 0):

for better performance use the below query to get the same result to optiomize the performance.

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, c.Time AS LastClock, c.ClockType
FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT EmployeeID, Time, ClockType
  FROM Clock
  WHERE Time = (SELECT MAX(Time) FROM Clock c1 WHERE c1.EmployeeID = Clock.EmployeeID)
) c ON e.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID
```